# kubernetes - Ingress network policy not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have 3 Kubernetes deployments and services for each of the deployments (namespace = firstspace).
each deployment is labelled as app1, app2, app3 in order.

As an example, if I run the following command. I will get the first pod as the result.

```
kubectl get pods -l app=app1 --namespace firstspace
```

My goal is to restrict the Ingress access of the third pod (app=app3) using the following Network Policy allowing traffic only from the second pod (app=app2) and any pods from another namespace called "secondspace".

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-app3
  namespace: firstspace
spec:
  podSelector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: app3
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: secondspace
    - podSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - {key: app, operator: In, values: [app2]}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

However, when I deploy the network policy to the "firstspace" namespace, I can still curl (and get a sample JSON response) the service of the third pod (app=app3) using the first pod (app=app1).

Following is a sample command. Here, 10.100.150.0 is the ClusterIP of the service created for the third pod.

```
kubectl exec app1-849b94c6df-rzdls --namespace firstspace-- curl -sL 10.100.150.0:8080/testendpoint
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it? Please also specify which exactly ingress did you use?

Comment: Kubernetes Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7".

I deployed it using the command `$ kubectl apply -f network.yaml`.

Comment: I think I'm using the default ingress.
Please note that I'm a newbie to Kubernetes.

Comment: Is your `network.yaml` file attached to the question? You need to specify exactly, ehich Kubernetes did you use: [Kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), [nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) or [nginx ingress for kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)?

Comment: Yes, the full content of the network.yaml file is in the question description.
The cluster I'm trying this uses nginx ingress.

Comment: I need to also know how did you create your cluster? Did you use some cloud provider (which?) or did you use bare metal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error, I observed the following.
According to the Kubernetes Network Policies [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), Deployed Network Policies will be only effective if a [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) is installed in the Kubernetes cluster.

Since my local [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/) cluster did not have a [network plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) the network policy I have mentioned in the question description was not effective.

After, installing the [Cillium Network Plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/network-policy-provider/cilium-network-policy/) in my [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/) cluster, the network policy worked as expected.

**Notes:**

- [Cillium Network Plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/network-policy-provider/cilium-network-policy/) installation was not successful on [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/) when using `docker` as the driver. But it worked when selected `hyperv` as the driver.
- I had to create an Egress policy as well for the pod with app=app2 label to allow egress traffic from the pod with app=app3 label (See the example below).

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: egress-app2
  namespace: firstspace
spec:
  podSelector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: app3
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

Comment: Upvoted! Calico failed but Cillium finally enfored the policies-Also, I'm using minikube with docker driver-